# why is case when failing when modifying date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return `1` between 1st and 14th and `first day of next month` for any other based on current day.

I can run very basic case when statement:

```
select 
case when datepart(d, getdate()) between 2 and 14 then '1'
      else '1st next month' end
```

which returns 1 or 1st next month as expected, and I can get actual first day of next month easily as well:

```
select DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(getdate()))
```

but when I combine it. It doesn't return anything - no error and no results
no matter what day is today

```
select 
case when datepart(d, getdate()) between 2 and 14 then '1'
      else DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(getdate()))  end
```

do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your final query is going to throw a conversion error since one outcome of the case statement is a string and the other is a datetime.

Comment: 2 different datatypes being returned here, one text `'1'`, one date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid datatype mismatch, output both as text:

```
select 
  case 
    when datepart(d, getdate()) between 2 and 14 then '1'
    else convert(varchar, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(getdate())),120)
  end
```